# MongoDB, include projection on fields nested in a certain field (but keep other parent fields)

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin

I currently do this, it works fine, but is perhaps a bit wasteful:

```
Aggregation.lookup("projects", "project_id", "_id", "project"),
Aggregation.unwind("project"),
Aggregation.addFields()
      .addField("project")
      .withValue(listOf(projectKeySet.map { it to "\$project.$it" }.toMap()))
      .build(),
Aggregation.unwind("project"),
```

Trying this, seems to not apply the *include projection* only to the fields inside the 'project' document. (it seems to be applying it to the whole document, such that even the fields alongside the 'project' field aren't included, if not mentioned)

```
Aggregation.lookup("projects", "project_id", "_id", "project"),
Aggregation.unwind("project"),
AggregationOperation {
    Document("\$project", Document("project", map(projectKeySet to 1)))
},
```

After applying some other downstream projection, I just get an empty []

This however does work! (it correctly excludes the project.country field, keeping the other document fields (alongside the parent project field), in tact. (This is an exclusion projection though)

```
Aggregation.lookup("projects", "project_id", "_id", "project"),
Aggregation.unwind("project"),
AggregationOperation {
   Document("\$project", Document("project", Document("country", 0))
},
```

My goal is to apply an include projection, but just to fields nested inside another field. I want the other parent fields to stay (without explicitly mentioning all of them, in the include projection), Is that possible? Otherwise I'll stick to my add fields method, overwriting the earlier contents of the field. 'project'